# Jmeter Maven Plugin - Remote server config with parameters in pom.xml

Tags: jmeter, pom.xml, dependency-management, parent-pom, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute a `jmeter` test using the maven plugin on a remote server leveraging a `pom.xml` file that is completely parameterized as below.(I was able to successfully run a `maven-jmeter` remote test, where the servername, port, protocol and other info are all hard coded in the `jmx` file.

My **pom.xml** file is below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
         <description>
    Executes a JMeter test.
  </description>
  <properties>
    <webapp.protocol>http</webapp.protocol>
    <!--<webapp.host>www.mozilla.com</webapp.host>-->
        <webapp.host>fsa-mia-dev2.fsalabs.io</webapp.host>
    <webapp.port>80</webapp.port>
    <test.duration>30</test.duration>
    <test.threads>10</test.threads>
  </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>

            <executions>
              <execution>
                <!--
                1)
                  first test run warms up the webserver.
                  Used to fill caches.
                  With a different set of properties since it runs much shorter than a normal test
                  and also the rate of requests/second may be much lower.
                  Maybe also use a different URL set.
                -->
                <id>warmup</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jmeter</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <propertiesUser>
                    <!--Accesses urls for warmup (compiles JSPs, fills caches, ...)-->

                                        <!--************Setup Config for Threadgroup 23***************-->
                                                            <threadgroup23.name>S23_SFA_Org_CO</threadgroup23.name>
                                        <threadgroup23.Transactionname>T23_SFA_Org_CO</threadgroup23.Transactionname>
                                        <threadgroup23.ThinkTime>5000</threadgroup23.ThinkTime>
                                          <threadgroup23.comment>T23_SFA_Org_CO</threadgroup23.comment>
                    <!--number of threads to use-->
                    <threadgroup23.numberOfThreads>5</threadgroup23.numberOfThreads>
                    <!--delay of the test in seconds-->
                    <threadgroup23.scheduledDelay>0</threadgroup23.scheduledDelay>
                    <!--duration of the test in seconds-->
                    <threadgroup23.scheduledDuration>60</threadgroup23.scheduledDuration>
                    <!--how long till all threads are up and running in seconds-->
                    <threadgroup23.rampUp>1</threadgroup23.rampUp>
                                        <threadgroup23.dataFile>/home/ubuntu/mproj/data/S23_SFA_Org_CO.dat</threadgroup23.dataFile>

                  </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              </executions>


  <configuration>
              <testFilesIncluded>
                <testFilesIncluded>01_SA_CU_GetCPS.jmx</testFilesIncluded>
              </testFilesIncluded>

              <!-- protocol, server and port of tested webapp -->
              <propertiesUser>
                <protocol>${webapp.protocol}</protocol>
                <server>${webapp.host}</server>
                <port>${webapp.port}</port>
              </propertiesUser>

<resultsFileFormat>csv</resultsFileFormat>
<testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
<ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
<remoteConfig>
<startServersBeforeTests>true</startServersBeforeTests>
<serverList>10.36.14.170</serverList>
</remoteConfig>
<suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>
<propertiesSystem>

</propertiesSystem>
<propertiesJMeter><log_level.jmeter>DEBUG</log_level.jmeter></propertiesJMeter>
</configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The issue is.. jmeter-server detects a request to execute and almost immediately stops.

Here is the info from **log** file post run

```
[debug] JMeter is called with the following command line arguments: -n -t /home/ubuntu/mProj/src/test/jmeter/01_SA_CU_GetCPS.jmx -l /home/ubuntu/mProj/target/jmeter/results/01_SA_CU_GetCPS.csv -d /home/ubuntu/mProj/target/jmeter -j /home/ubuntu/mProj/target/jmeter/logs/01_SA_CU_GetCPS.jmx.log -r -R 10.36.14.170
[info] Executing test: 01_SA_CU_GetCPS.jmx
[info] Created the tree successfully using /home/ubuntu/mProj/src/test/jmeter/01_SA_CU_GetCPS.jmx
[info] Configuring remote engine for 10.36.14.170
[info] Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.36.14.170:37913](remote),objID:[-10468c89:14fba100421:-7fff, -1854422229136130507]]]
[info] Starting remote engines
[info] Starting the test @ Fri Sep 11 01:42:27 UTC 2015 (1441935747716)
[info] Remote engines have been started
[info] Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
[info] Tidying up remote @ Fri Sep 11 01:42:29 UTC 2015 (1441935749973)
[info] Completed Test: 01_SA_CU_GetCPS.jmx
[INFO]
[INFO] Test Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests Run: 1, Failures: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.280s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 11 01:42:35 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/57M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(The pom-file works well without the remoteConfig - in localhost)
(There's no networking issues any where and the remote server is able to access the host and works when servername, port, protocol is hardcoded in jmx files)
Is this a known limitation of the `maven-jmeter` plugin?

Comment: Are the remote servers defined in your jmeter.properties file?  (See https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Remote-Server-Configuration for more information on remote running)

Comment: Yes (jmeter.properties contains the remote servers). I was able to run the same exact test successfully on the remote server with the servername, protocol and port hard coded inside the jmx file.  Any chance that this might actually be a limitation of the jmeter-maven plugin. Based on the log post above, I dont see jmeter-maven plugin sending in these parameters to the remote server. Thanks Ardesco

Comment: It's using the remote parameters, from your log the command line arguments include "-r -R 10.36.14.170"

Comment: It;s quite possible it is a limitation of the plugin that's not known about.  The plugin just configures JMeter and then runs JMeter so it could be that something has been missed.

Comment: Thanks Ardesco. One way I have worked around this is to move out the configuration( servername, protocol, port, threadgroup23.xxx) into another config.xml file which is in a common location shared by all jmeter slaves.

Answer (score 1):

**First use a recent version of [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin), 2.8.3 as of 15th january 2019**.

To pass parameters, enter in pom.xml as child of **configuration**:

```
    <propertiesJMeter>
         <BUILD_TAG>${project.version}</BUILD_TAG>
         <threads>7</threads>
         <duration>30</duration>
     </propertiesJMeter>
```

And in jmeter, to use threads for example, you would use [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function:

> ${__P(threads,5)

This [blog](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/) explains the whole process.

Comment: It worked for me via command line argument also, thank you!
In XML:
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${__P(hostname,1)}</stringProp>
In POM:
                            <propertiesJMeter>
                                <hostname>${hostname}</hostname>
And command argument simply:
-Dhostname=www.mozilla.com